# Next 13 with Prisma DB: Seed.ts not working

Tags: postgresql, next.js, server-side-rendering, prisma, supabase

I'm building a web app with Next 13. I'm using Prisma for my ORM with SupaBase hosting my Postgres database. I've been following a modern Next 13 course updated about a month ago and I'm at the stage of seeding my database. The course provides a `seed.ts` to put in the `/api` directory. The course then says to navigate to `localhost:3000/api/seed` but when I navigated to that directory I got the default Next 13 404 page. Then the course says to check Supabase to see the seeded data that should have been added. However, no data is there; but, there are API `get` requests.

### SupaBase Project Homepage:

[image: SupaBase homepage]

Above is a picture of my SupaBase homepage. At the fastest left card, you can see 11 API requests.

### SupaBase Table:

[image: SupBase Table]

Above is a picture of one of my data tables. As shown there is no data in them from the seed.

In the `seed.ts` file I'm also getting many cryptic Typescript errors. They all are throwing errors on parts of my code like this:

```
 main_image:
 "https://resizer.otstatic.com/v2/photos/wide-huge/1/32109459.jpg",
```

Throwing this error:

```
Type '{ name: string; main_image: string; price: "REGULAR"; description: string; images: string[]; open_time: string; close_time: string; slug: string; location_id: number; cuisine_id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'RestaurantCreateManyInput'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'main_image' does not exist in type 'RestaurantCreateManyInput'. Did you mean to write 'main_img'?ts(2322)
```

The full project is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/tech-world-code/open-table-clone/tree/main).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The seed file should be place under
app/api/hello/route.ts
and then hit Url http://localhost:3000/api/hello in the browser than your data will be update in Supabase database

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

1. Put seed.ts file inside app dir
2. install the below dev dependencies

> npm install -D typescript ts-node @types/node

3. add these lines in package.json file

   ```
    "prisma": {
   "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} app/seed.ts"},
   ```
4. remove the NextRequest and NextResponse from the seed.ts file and add these lines below the handler function

> handler()
> .then(async () => {
> await prisma.$disconnect()
> })
> .catch(async (e) => {
> console.error(e)
> await prisma.$disconnect()
> process.exit(1)
> })

5. run this command

> npx prisma db seed

this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

you created `seed.ts` in experimental `app` directory.

you have to create it in `pages/api/seed.ts`.

Regarding the `image` error, you use images in seed.ts from this domain:  `resizer.otstatic.com/`. since you use it in the wrong directory, I think it is considered to be used on the client side (although app components are processed on the server, eventually they are shipped to the browser and browser displays it), so you have to add this config in `next.config.js`. example from [docs:](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'example.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/account123/**',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

But once you passed the `seed.ts` to the `pages/api` directory, you won't need to add that config because that configuration's purpose is:

> To protect your application from malicious users, configuration is
> required in order to use external images. This ensures that only
> external images from your account can be served from the Next.js Image
> Optimization API.

Comment: Hasn't the ```/api``` folder been moved to the app directory?

Answer (score 0):

Some projects may require you to add compile options. When using Next.js for example, you would setup your seed script like so:

package.json

```
"prisma": {
  "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
},
```

To seed the database, run the db seed CLI command:

```
npx prisma db seed
```

https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-migrate/workflows/seeding